# Unable to convert function return value to a Python type

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++14, pybind11

I want to bind a c++ function to python using pybind11.
The c++ function returns:

```
auto tree_fusion_depth_map(const hg::tree & tree_1, const hg::tree & tree_2, const hg::tree & tree_3) {
   //some code here
   return xt::eval(xt::view(depth, xt::range(0, nleaves)));
```

When I call the function in python I get:

```
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    (arg0: higra.higram.Tree, arg1: higra.higram.Tree, arg2: higra.higram.Tree) -> xt::xtensor_container<xt::uvector<long, xsimd::aligned_allocator<long, 16ul> >, 1ul, (xt::layout_type)1, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>
```

This is the python module and docstrings in c++ code:

```
        PYBIND11_MODULE(mbfusion, m)
        {
            xt::import_numpy();

            m.doc() = R"pbdoc(
                An example higra extension
            )pbdoc";

            m.def("function", function, "An example function.");

        }
```

How can I solve this issue?